# Showing catogory based post in any existing page

Tags: wordpress

I am new in WordPress. Using the Storefront theme, I created 5 pages, and all posts show on the home page, but I want any specific category based post to show on any page not home page, this home page [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KGqG.png).

This is another page where I will show any category based post [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LZLm.png).

Comment: Your question makes so sense. Any way to improve your English?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show posts by category simple pass category name  with args of while loop see,
$args = array('post_type'=$post_name,'category_name'=$cat_name);

Comment: i am not clear , when i creat new page it show blank  but i want one or two category post show in defferent page